# Wrong scale in a stacked ybar logarithmic plot with basis 10 using package pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want the plot described in the title.  So I added options `log basis y=10` and `ybar stacked` to the `axis` environment.  The scale becomes wrong.  If I add just one option, the scale is right.  Is my mistake or a bug in package `pgfplots`?  I am using `pgfplots` version 1.5.1, and `pgf/tikz` version 2.10.  An example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[ymode=log
%                , log basis y=10
%                , ybar stacked
                 ]
          \addplot coordinates {(0,1e5)};
          \addplot coordinates {(0,9e5)};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[ymode=log
                , log basis y=10
%                , ybar stacked
                 ]
          \addplot coordinates {(0,1e5)};
          \addplot coordinates {(0,9e5)};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[ymode=log
%                , log basis y=10
                , ybar stacked
                 ]
          \addplot coordinates {(0,1e5)};
          \addplot coordinates {(0,9e5)};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[ymode=log
                , log basis y=10
                , ybar stacked
                 ]
          \addplot coordinates {(0,1e5)};
          \addplot coordinates {(0,9e5)};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pgfplots 1.5.1.

I will look into it. Thanks for the report.

By the way: feel free to send issues which appear to be bugs to the sourceforge bug trackers of pgfplots.